# Download files using the webcontentLink

Tags: google-drive-api

I have been trying to download the file using the Mediahttpdownloader and passing the webcontentlink of the file. However, it always fails with a 401 unauthorised.

```
MediaHttpDownloader downloader = new MediaHttpDownloader(httpTransport, drive.getRequestFactory().getInitializer());
downloader.download(new GenericUrl(file.getWebContentLink()), out);
```

I have tried adding the authorization header but it still fails:

```
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();     
            requestHeaders.setAuthorization("Bearer "+ credential.getAccessToken());
downloader.download(new GenericUrl(file.getWebContentLink(), requestHeaders,  out);
```

I have also tried adding the access token to the URL, but it still fails with 401 unauthorzied.

```
downloader.download(new GenericUrl(file.getWebContentLink()+"?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"), out);
```

Here is the exact error:

```
401 Unauthorized
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any idea how to use the Webcontent Link with the Mediahttpdownloader class?

Comment: something is wrong with your drive service in .   drive.getRequestFactory().getInitializer());  you aren't authenticated.

Comment: Well, upload just works fine. If I put the WebContentLink+?access_token=TOKEN in the browser, it works fine , but doesn't work in the code with the Mediahttpdownloader class.

Here is how it is initialized:
`drive = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
     APPLICATION_NAME).build();}`

And the same drive service works fine when I use:
`drive.files().get(uploadedFile.getId()).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);`

Comment: your drive service in your download is not fine.   are you using the same drive service variable?

Comment: Yes, it is the same.

I can download when using the file executeMediaAndDownloadTo function
`drive.files().get(uploadedFile.getId()).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);`

Comment: Also, the web content link is supposed to work for unauthorised access as mentioned in the documentation:

_If you want to allow an unauthorized user to view a file directly in a web browser instead of through the API, use the webContentLink._

Comment: your webContentLink have value? if value is nil, you need set query.field.

Comment: Yes, it has the value. I can use that to open in a browser, but even there I have to authenticate or add access_token to the link.

Comment: You will be getting this error if the content is not publicly shared. You may want to use downloadUrl: Download a file — `files.get` with `alt=media` or Download and export a Google Doc —` files.export`. For more information kindly look into [access non google files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21530483/5995040) and [downloadUrl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11731117/5995040)

Comment: But v3 does not have downloadUrl.